# Questions about socket module's .accept() return value of python

Tags: python, sockets

I am very new to python and I am having a problem with using socket module to set up TCP connections. Here is part of my code:

```
clients = {}
addresses = {}

HOST = ''
PORT = 33000
BUFSIZ = 1024
ADDR = (HOST, PORT)
SERVER = socket(AF_INET, SOCK_STREAM)
SERVER.bind(ADDR)

def accept_incoming_connections():
    while True:
       client, client_address = SERVER.accept()
       print ("The Client is: ")
       print (client.raddr)
       print ("%s:%s has connected." % clinet_address)
       client.send(bytes("Greetings from the cave!" + "Now type your name and press enter!"),"utf8")
       addresses[client] = client_address
       Thread(target = handle_client, args = (client,)).start()
```

at the code here:

```
client,client_address = SERVER.accept()
```

I try to make the variable 'client_address' store the IP address of the client, but while running it, it turns out getting nothing. This variable was not assigned any value at all. After I checked the value stored in 'client', I found this :

```
'<socket.socket fd=4, family=AddressFamily.AF_INET, type=SocketKind.SOCK_STREAM, proto=0, laddr=('10.146.0.2', 33000), raddr=('104.38.51.137', 62283)>'
```

in the 'raddr' part, I found my client IP address and port, so why is that? I do remember the accept() function has two return valve. If there is really only one return value, how am I suppose to extract the client IP and port from this return valve?

just in case of need, I will also post my client code here:

```
import socket               # Import Socket module
import time

myname = input ("input you username>>")
s = socket.socket()         # Create a Socket object
ip= "35.200.59.31" 
port = 33000                # setup port number

s.connect((ip, port))
s.send(bytes(myname, encoding="utf-8"))
print (s.recv(1024))
username=str(input("input user name>>"))
s.send(bytes(username))

flag=True
while flag:
    signal=s.recv(1024)
    if signal == (bytes("xxx", encoding = "utf-8")):
        tosend=(input(">>>"))
        s.send(bytes(tosend))
        print (">>",tosend)
        if tosend=="quit":
            flag = False
    else :
        print (">>>",signal)
s.close()
```

Comment: It is impossible for `client,client_address = SERVER.accept()` to succeed, yet not assign anything to `client_address`.  Try printing it out directly (without trying to format it as `%s:%s`), or try printing `type(client_address)`.

Comment: @jasonharper It returns a 'tuple' type, so it should contain a tuple... But when I try to print it, it still says that the client_address is not defined.

Comment: Ok i try to print client_address[1] and it now returns my client address. But i still don't get it, why i can not print the whole tuple out.

Comment: Perhaps the confusion between `client` and `clinet` that you have throughout the code?

Comment: Now I solved the client_address problem. I replaced all client_address with client_Address[0]. But now in the part:
    
    `client.send(bytes("Greetings from the cave!" + "Now type your name and press enter!"), "utf8")`

It said that it requires an integer and I don't know what is happening.

Comment: @jasonharper Thanks for reminding me that! I fixed it now, but I still have the problem in client.send().

Comment: @DeSantaMichell That's because of a misplaced parenthesis. You currently say: `client.send(bytes("message"), "UTF-8")`. You're supposed to say: `client.send(bytes("message", "UTF-8"))`. UTF-8 is a parameter to bytes, not client.send(..).

Comment: @UltraInstinct Thank you! I noticed that too and it works fine now! BTW, is "UTF-8" works totally same as "utf8"?

Comment: But I still don't quite understand why I cannot just use the tuple directly. My friend tried this and he is working fine, we are all running this on Linux and python3.

Comment: It should work, unless you have a typo like you did above. Update the post with both the actual code and the error for us to take another look.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thanks, everyone! my problem is basically solved. Here is the fixed codes:

```
clients = {}
addresses = {}

HOST = ''
PORT = 33000
BUFSIZ = 1024
ADDR = (HOST, PORT)
SERVER = socket(AF_INET, SOCK_STREAM)
SERVER.bind(ADDR)

def accept_incoming_connections():
    while True:
       client, client_address = SERVER.accept()
       print ("The Client address is: ")
       print (client_address[0])
       print (str(client_address[0]) + " has connected.")
       client.send(bytes("Greetings from the cave!" + "Now type your name and press enter!",'utf8'))
       addresses[client] = client_address[0]
           Thread(target = handle_client, args = (client,)).start()
```

Though there are still a few other problems(probably logic problems), at least it will compile and run now. Again, thanks!